# Installing an apk on sdcard from PC using ADB for testing and take screenshot

Tags: android, adb, monkeyrunner

I am using an ADB or android debugging bridge for the the first time.

The problem is I have written a code to download the APK from the market on the device directly. Now I want to run the ADB to install the downloaded apk and take screenshots.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Install apk file programmatically .

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()  + "/barcode.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

**first copy apk file to sd card programmatically and then do the above step **

**OR**

Step-by-Step way to install android apk to emulator:

```
1) Install Android SDK
2) Start the emulator by going to $SDK_root/emulator.exe
3) Go to command prompt and go to the directory $SDK_root/platform-tools 
4) Type in the command adb install
5) Now ur app is up and running on the emulator
```

Look at [this link](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-take-screenshots-of-android-device/) to capture screen shot through ADB.

Comment: my apk is there in the sdk card..so and i give the command on the terminal, so how shall the apk on the sdcard get installed

Comment: adb install D:/download/test.apk